How to define the metric tensor on a general 2D surface.
How to get the metric tensor on a general 2D surface such as $z = x(x^2-y^2)$ ?
I know how to do this on a sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ because there is a spherical coordinate system. But there is no such curve coordinate on a general 2D surface. Howerver I think this question maybe very simple I just got confused about some concepts. Anyone has some ideas ? Thanks.

Your surface admits an obvious parameterization since it is the graph of a function.

Hello, am I doing the right thing? @Moishe Kohan let $x = \bar{x}$, $y = \bar{y}$, $z = \bar{x}(\bar{x}^2 - \bar{y}^2)$. Then $g_{\bar{x}\bar{x}} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial \bar{x}} \frac{\partial x}{\partial \bar{x}} g_{xx} +  \frac{\partial y}{\partial \bar{x}} \frac{\partial y}{\partial \bar{x}} g_{yy} +  \frac{\partial z}{\partial \bar{x}} \frac{\partial z}{\partial \bar{x}} g_{zz} = 1+(3\bar{x}^2 - \bar{y}^2)^2$

No: You do not need the new variables $\bar x, \bar y$, just use $x$ and $y$ as your parameters.

Yes, you are right. Thanks.  @Moishe Kohan
